# How to create a save button in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I have a game and I used Flash cs5 ActionScript3. I want to create a save button for the game. When the player loads the game, the saved game will open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [`SharedObject`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) class; particularly its [`data`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#data) property.

Essentially:

1. Define a `SharedObject` like so:

   `var saveData:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("MyGame");`
2. Use the `data` property to store information which will be accessible the next time you open the application. It's important to note that the data will only be retained if the `.swf` remains in the same location, either on the web or locally.

   `if(!saveData.data.test)` 
           `saveData.data.test = "Test string";`
3. You'll be able to access the information you've stored in the `data` object as expected:

   `trace(saveData.data.test); // Test string`

The idea is that initially you'll create all of the properties that you may want to save when the game launches for the first time:

```
if(!saveData.data.ready)
{
    saveData.data.ready = true;

    saveData.data.playerHealth = 100;
    saveData.data.levelsUnlocked = 1;
}
```

And when you hit "save", overwrite these properties:

```
function save(so:SharedObject):void
{
    so.data.playerHealth = player.health;
    so.data.levelsUnlocked = currentLevel;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marty Wallace. How about saving the current timeline. For example, when I played the flash file, it stopped at frame 5. Then if I want to load the flash file again, it should be at frame 5. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: So something like saveData.data.frame = currentFrame; and then when you load the game: gotoAndStop(saveData.data.frame);

Comment: Sir @Marty Wallace. I have this type of error during saving. Test string
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::MouseEvent@300ba0e1 to flash.net.SharedObject.

What do you think is the problem sir?

Comment: @GenesisJohnDagdag Somewhere you're trying to cast an instance of `MouseEvent` to `SharedObject`. I suggest posting another question with relevant code so I can better help you.